# how to share data between docker container and host

Tags: css, docker, docker-compose

I'm working on a read the docs documentation where I use docker. To customize it, I d like to share the `css` folder between the container and host, in order to avoid building always a new image to see the changes. The goal is, that I can just refresh the browser and see the changes.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
docker run -v ~/docs/source/_static/css:/docs/source/_static/css -p 80:80 -it my-docu:latest
```

What is wrong in this command?

The path of the folder I'd like to share is:

```
Documents/my-documentation/docs/source/_static/css
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What operating system are you using? Mac, Linux, Windows?

Comment: I'm working on a Mac

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the ~ does not resolve correctly. The tilde character ("~") refers to the home directory of your user; usually something like `/home/your_username`.

In your case, it sounds like your document isn't in this directory anyway.

Try:

```
docker run -v Documents/my-documentation/docs/source/_static/css:/docs/source/_static/css -p 80:80 -it my-docu:latest
```

Comment: This command doesn't work, I get following error message: `docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: 
The path /documents/my-documentation/docs/source/_static/css
is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.` but I checked my File Sharing settings form docker and there `Users/` is added.

Comment: I think we're probably going to need help from a Mac OS user. Sorry that I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

I have no mac to test with, but I suspect the command should be as below (`Documents` is a subfolder to inside your home directory denoted by `~`)

```
docker run -v ~/Documents/my-documentation/docs/source/_static/css:/docs/source/_static/css -p 80:80 -it my-docu:latest
```

In your OP you mount the host folder `~/docs/source/_static/css`, which does not make sense if your files are in `Documents/my-documentation/docs/source/_static/css` as that would correspond to `~/Documents/my-documentation/docs/source/_static/css`

Keep in mind that Docker is still running inside a VM on Mac, so you will need to give a host path that is valid on that VM

What you can do to get a better view of the situation is to start an interactive container where you mount the root file system of the host vm root into `/mnt/vm-root`. That way you can see what paths are available to mount and how they should be formatted when you pass them using the `-v` flag to the docker run command

```
docker run --rm -it -w /mnt/vm-root -v /:/mnt/vm-root ubuntu:latest bash
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried `docker run -v ~/Documents/my-documentation/docs/source/_static/css:/docs/source/_static/css -p 80:80 -it my-docu:latest` but it doesn't work. Docker starts the image but changes in the css file doesn't appear...

Comment: Okay, but you can access the files through the container, just that the changes are not reflected?